How to generate an integer that repeats like 100100100…1 in binary with time complexity O(n)?
I am making a function that takes length:int and distance:int as inputs, and output the largest integer that satisfies the following properties in its binary representation:

It starts with 1, ends with 1

There are distance - 1 many 0 between each 1

Its length is strictly less than length


It could be implemented as the following:
def repeatdigit(length:int, distance:int) -> int:
   result = 0
   pointer = 1
   for _ in range(1, length, distance):
      result |= pointer
      pointer <<= distance
   return result

For example: repeatdigit(10,3)==0b1001001 , repeatdigit(15,4)=0b1000100010001. I’m only caring about binary because I need to use it as a tool of bit manipulation. In practice, length will be very big,  distance ** 2 < length. Assuming the input is valid.
As its name suggested, it is repeating a same pattern over and over.
An explicit formula:
result = (1 << (length+distance-2 - ((length-2) % distance)))//((1 << distance) - 1)

But both algorithm are slow, their time complexity is O(n²), where n = length.
Doing similar things with list only takes O(n). Namely ([1]+[0]*(distance-1)) * ((length-2)//distance) + [1]
(Context: I want to make such an integer so that I don’t need to store 0 and 1 in a very long list as it is space consuming)
How do I make such an integer in O(n)?

n is not the value of length; it's the logarithm of length (or rather, the logarithm of length + distance).

You would probably be better off using the bitarray package.

@chepner It's their question, they get to define it, not us. If their definition causes an issue, then point out that issue. (And I btw don't see an issue with that.)

Sorry, I didn’t test my code thoroughly. Now the bugs should be fixed

If you need a random-access mutable sequence data type, ints make a terrible substitute. This isn't the only operation where trying to use ints like a list will be terrible for performance.

@user2357112 Can be alright, depends on the case. I've similarly used giant ints a few times with good success, once or twice even needed something like this question's patterns, where I then did something like I did in my answer.

@KellyBundy: For use cases that don't actually need random access, ints can work okay. But even just reading a single bit will take time proportional to the index you're trying to read. The set of operations that can be supported with reasonable performance when trying to use an int like a sequence is highly restrictive, and even if a use case happens to fit within that set of operations, requirements changes can easily take you out of that set.

@nocomment No, the size of the input for complexity analysis is a well-defined concept. The magnitude of a particular argument isn't it.

@chepner Nowhere are they saying that n is the size of the input. Or am I overlooking it? It seems you're imagining that.

Doubling the number of 1-bits instead of adding them just one at a time:
def repeatdigit(length:int, distance:int) -> int:
   def f(want):
      if want == 1:
         return 1
      have = (want + 1) // 2
      x = f(have)
      add = min(have, want - have)
      return x | (x << (add * distance))
   ones = 1 + (length - 2) // distance
   return f(ones)

My ones, want, have and add refer to numbers of 1-bits.
The add = min(have, want - have) could be "simplified", as I either add have or have - 1 1-bits. It comes from this earlier, slightly less optimal version:
def repeatdigit(length:int, distance:int) -> int:
   result = 1
   want = 1 + (length-2) // distance
   have = 1
   while have < want:
      add = min(have, want - have)
      result |= result << (add * distance)
      have += add
   return result


Why the one that uses recursive function call will be faster than the while loop version? I remembered that function calls are expensive. I’m just curious.

@Mr.W With very big lengths, the few function calls are insignificant. Almost all time will be spent by the int operations. Now let's say we want 17 ones. The recursive version will build values with 17, 9, 5, 3, 2 and 1 ones, 37 total. The while-loop one will build values with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 17 ones, 48 total. It's cheaper to build 17 from combining 9 and 9, wasting just 1 overlapped. Compared to combining 16 and 16, wasting 15 overlapped.
